# I am wondering if magnets can be safely used to connect power from one to the other?

Tags: power, transfer-function, magnetics, electromagnetic

I am thinking of trying to create a extension cord that can be taken apart or separated as needed. And rejoined at any length of cord but connected only through magnetic connections. So I'm wondering could magnets transfer or carry 240 v or 120 v without loss of voltage and also safely.

Comment: "Magnets" is a broad category of material. But most likely the magnetic material isn't making the connection, whatever it's coated in would. So then you have to look at material properties, thickness, etc.

Comment: What advantage do you think this would give over traditional plug/socket connectors?

Answer (score 1):

The magnets will be safe enough, they won't go bang, or suffer any other injury.

However, if you have exposed metal surfaces carrying 240 V (I'm not sure how else you could make a magnetic connector for an extension cord) then you will not be safe.

Answer (score 1):

That would probably work, however the hot side would need to be protected and not exposed. Make sure you follow proper IEC and IPC creepage and clearance distances. This [IEC Standard](https://www.lockingpowercords.com/iec-60309-extension-cables) might also be applicable. One problem that might also arise with using magnets is hot-plugging and arcing when the cord is attached and detached, you may need to do testing and coat the magnets with a more arc friendly coating than the magnets surface to prevent pitting from the arcs.